# how do i get these Object Key Values into the textboxes?

Tags: javascript

I'v been trying to get the values of each key in a object string into textboxes but having issues

if anyone could hep me out and point me in the right direction as to where im going wrong id appreciate it thank you.

this is a small version of what im working with.

```
<form name=formtest>

<input type=text id = text1 size=10 value=""/>
<input type=text id = text2 size=10 value=""/>
<input type=text id = text3 size=10 value=""/>
<input type=text id = text4 size=10 value=""/>
<input type=text id = text5 size=10 value=""/>
<input type=text id = text6 size=10 value=""/>
<input type=text id = text7 size=10 value=""/>
<input type=text id = text8 size=10 value=""/>
<input type=button id = calculate value = calculate onclick = calculate()/>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function calculate() {  

var attackerTroops = {"Peasants":"222,111","Militia":"333,444","Spies":"22,1","Arsonists":"1111,1000"};

var peas =  'Peasants';
var mili =  'Miltia';
var spies =  'Spies';
var arson =  'Arsonists';

console.log(attackerTroops[peas]);
console.log(attackerTroops[mili]);
console.log(attackerTroops[spies]);
console.log(attackerTroops[arson);

document.formtest.text1.value =(peas[0])
document.formtest.text2.value =(peas[1])
document.formtest.text3.value =(mili[0])
document.formtest.text4.value =(mili[1])
document.formtest.text5.value =(spies[0])
document.formtest.text6.value =(spies[1])
document.formtest.text7.value =(arson[0])
document.formtest.text8.value =(arson[1])

}       
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
    try this:

<form name=formtest>

<input type=text id = text1 size=10 value=""/>
<input type=text id = text2 size=10 value=""/>
<input type=text id = text3 size=10 value=""/>
<input type=text id = text4 size=10 value=""/>
<input type=text id = text5 size=10 value=""/>
<input type=text id = text6 size=10 value=""/>
<input type=text id = text7 size=10 value=""/>
<input type=text id = text8 size=10 value=""/>
<input type=button id = calculate value = calculate onclick ="javascript:calculate1()"/>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function calculate1() {  

var attackerTroops = {"Peasants":"222,111","Militia":"333,444","Spies":"22,1","Arsonists":"1111,1000"};

peas = attackerTroops.Peasants.split(',');
spies = attackerTroops.Spies.split(',');
mili = attackerTroops.Militia.split(',');
arson = attackerTroops.Arsonists.split(',');

document.formtest.text1.value =(peas[0])
document.formtest.text2.value =(peas[1])
document.formtest.text3.value =(mili[0])
document.formtest.text4.value =(mili[1])
document.formtest.text5.value =(spies[0])
document.formtest.text6.value =(spies[1])
document.formtest.text7.value =(arson[0])
document.formtest.text8.value =(arson[1])
}
</script>
```

Comment: you need to access value like this attackerTroops[peas] and then do split by comma.

Comment: ty @nur but where and how do u mean split by comma?

Comment: what i understood from your question that you want to 222,111 are two value which you want to access as 222 at 0th index and 111 as 1st index. so i thought attackerTroops[peas] will give access to "222,111" and if i split "222,111" by comma then i can get 222 and 111. please clarify if i am wrong.

Comment: yes that it what i want but i need them to go into certain textboxes

Answer (score 0):

First there are some changes I would like to suggest.

- Do not bind events using onclick attribute. Instead bind  in
  javascript.
- Have a common class for each object text boxes so that    you can
  target them directly

So you HTML would look like something below

```
<form name=formtest>
    <input type=text class="textbox Peasants" size=10 value="" />
    <input type=text class="textbox Peasants"  size=10 value="" />
    <input type=text class="textbox Militia"  size=10 value="" />
    <input type=text class="textbox Militia" size=10 value="" />
    <input type=text class="textbox Spies"  size=10 value="" />
    <input type=text class="textbox Spies" size=10 value="" />
    <input type=text class="textbox Arsonists"  size=10 value="" />
    <input type=text class="textbox Arsonists" size=10 value="" />
    <input type=button id=calculate value=calculate />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
var calculateButton = document.getElementById('calculate');

calculateButton.addEventListener('click', calculate);

function calculate() {
    var attackerTroops = {
        "Peasants": "222,111",
            "Militia": "333,444",
            "Spies": "22,1",
            "Arsonists": "1111,1000"
    };
    var keys = ['Peasants', 'Militia', 'Spies', 'Arsonists'];
    debugger;
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        // Gets the class name
        var className = keys[i];
        // Now access the elements based on the class name.
        var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
        // Get the values based on the attackerTroops object
        // Split it using comma to get the array
        var vals = attackerTroops[className].split(',');
        // Iterate over each element based on the class name and set the value
        for (var j = 0; j < elems.length; j++) {
            elems[j].value = vals[j];
        }
    }
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FQKbb/)**

Comment: ty and each key has 2 different values i want each textbox to have the appropriate 1 how would i do that?

Comment: im not sure what happened there i got upper then lower case letters in the textboxes? it took the 1st and 2nd letters of each key not the values?

Comment: ty but it didnt put the values in the textboxes? i understand what your doing but that confuses me more as to why it didnt?

Comment: its ok tyvm for ur effort :)

Comment: i found out why it wasnt it was the ''debugger;'' line :)